# How to clear String[] data in android

Tags: android, list

In my application I want use String[] to get data from server and for this I **write below codes :**

```
    private String[] chipCloudList;
chipCloudList = searchResponse.getData().getMostlyMatchedKeywordsText();
```

**My data from server :**

```
"mostlyMatchedKeywordsText": [
      "item1",
      "item2",
      "item3",
      "item4",
      "item5",
      "item6"
    ]
```

I can add data into **`chipCloudList`** but how can I **clear** this data?

Please help me <3

Comment: You're not really "adding data into" chipCloudList - you are setting a reference to point to the primitive String[] returned by searchResponse.getData().getMostlyMatchedKeywordsText().  So if you want to clear this reference, you can set chipCloudList to null.

Comment: @MichaelKrause, can you send to me code? please . I really need your help

Comment: It would be helpful to know what "clear" means to you and why you want to do it.

Comment: @MichaelKrause, with this code chipCloudList = searchResponse.getData().getMostlyMatchedKeywordsText(); I can fill data . ok? I have clear it. such as this chipCloudList.clear(). but in Sting[]  in can't use .clear()

Comment: @MichaelKrause, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you are getting back from your search response is a primitive String[] that you want to turn into a List that you can later reuse.

You can do something like this:

```
    List<String> cloudChipList = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings = 
             searchResponse.getData().getMostlyMatchedKeywordsText();

    for (String str : mostlyMatchedKeywordsStrings) {
        chipCloudList.add(str);
    }

    // Sometime later - you can clear this list 
    // and reuse for something else like so

    chipCloudList.clear();
```

Comment: thanks man, I try your code. but not show me any data into chipCloud view!

Comment: Are you wanting to show this data in a ListView or RecyclerView?  You'll need to use an ArrayAdapter or RecyclerView.Adapter to tie the data you got to your view.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ArrayList** of string i.e

> `List<String> chipCloudList = new ArrayList<>()`

**ArrayList** have **clear** method to clear all values.

> `chipCloudList.clear()`

.

Comment: I should use String[] , and in this I can't use .clear()

Comment: try this: `String[] test = new String[]{ "item1",
      "item2",
      "item3",
      "item4",
      "item5",
      "item6"};
      test = new String[0];`

Comment: Bro I can't spoon-feed you. Use your logic too. It's just an example to give you idea how you can clear a string array.

Answer (score -1):

you can try these:

chipCloudList.removeAll();

Comment: chipCloudList is a primitive String[] not a List